# Deinit not called in special circumstance that involves NSHashTable

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, deinit

I came across something that's peculiar and interesting and would love to get inputs from anyone.  So to start off with lets take this definition of the class:

```
class TestClass:NSObject {  
    var s1 = NSHashTable<TestClass>(options: .weakMemory)  

    func doit(bla:TestClass) {  
        s1.add(bla)  
        bla.s1.add(self)  
    }  

    deinit {  
        print("Deinit")  
    }  
}
```

Now lets consider the following:

```
var t1:TestClass? = TestClass()  
var t2:TestClass? = TestClass()
```

If we did the following deinit gets called:

```
t1?.s1.add(t2!)  
t2?.s1.add(t1!)  

t1 = nil // This will result in deinit being called
```

Now lets do the same thing but by calling doit() method

```
t1?.doit(bla:t2!)  

t1 = nil // Deinit doesn't get called for some reason
```

The question here is why isn't deinit being called in this situation?  What is so different about this since it essentially has the same reference assignment as the first method?

I would love to get input from anyone on this.

Comment: How have you tested your code? The line `t1?.doit(t2!)` does not compile in Swift 3. As far as I tested, both codes (`t1?.doit(t2!)` fixed as `t1?.doit(bla: t2!)`) have shown **`Deinit`** at the line `t1 = nil`. (Xcode 8.2.1, Command Line Tool project)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in either Swift 3.0.2 or Swift 3.1.

Comment: Sorry corrected this code

Comment: @OOPer I ran the `doit()` method call on my playground (same xcode version) and `Deinit` doesn't get printed at all.  It only printed with the first method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the problem is that you are trying to test this *in a playground*. Don't. Playgrounds are the work of the devil.

Test in an actual app project and you will see that `deinit` is called.

Example (iOS, but the equivalent in macOS would do fine):

```
import UIKit

class TestClass:NSObject {
    var s1 = NSHashTable<TestClass>(options: .weakMemory)
    func doit(bla:TestClass) {
        s1.add(bla)
        bla.s1.add(self)
    }
    deinit {
        print("Deinit")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var t1:TestClass? = TestClass()
    var t2:TestClass? = TestClass()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        t1?.doit(bla:t2!)
        t1 = nil // --> "Deinit"
        print(t2?.s1) // --> it's empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`deinit` is not called because you've created [reference cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID52).

First you're creating sctrong reference from `self` to `bla`: `s1.add(bla)`

Second you create strong reference from `bla` to `self`: `bla.s1.add(self)`

And now they both have references to each other, so they won't `deinit` if you just nullify one of them.

I've modified your `TestClass` to remove reference cycle:

```
class TestClass:NSObject {
  weak var s1 = NSHashTable<TestClass>(options: .weakMemory)

  func doit(bla:TestClass) {
    s1?.add(bla)
    bla.s1?.add(self)
  }

  deinit {
    print("Deinit")
  }
}
```

Now your second call will trigger `deinit` properly.

Comment: There is no reference cycle, as `NSHashTable` holds weak references to the objects added.

Comment: You can test it yourself: `t1?.doit(t2!)

print("t1 = \(t1!)")

t1 = nil

print(t2!.s1.allObjects) // here you will see t1 address`

Comment: Nope, I just get `[]` printed, as I would expect, as the hash table holds weak references to the objects added when `.weakMemory` is provided for the `options:` (feel free to [check the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspointerfunctions.options/1415896-weakmemory)).

Comment: I see the options, but for me, it's still there even after I do `t1 = nil`

Comment: With regards to @Hamish, that's the point of setting s1 to `.weakMemory` so that the reference held are weak relationships.  Because they are weakly held `t1 = nil` should be able to be released